# problem with autoscroll listview in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I need my listview to perform autoscroll as elements are added, to do this I implement a class that inherits from listview, it works, but it has a weakness, when you add equal elements it scrolls to the first one that is visible, let me explain Better you add several elements for example

1. C#
2. Html
3. T-SQL
4. Python
5. PL-SQL
6. PL-SQL

Here, instead of scrolling to the last PL-SQL, it stays on the first, it shows me the animation that a scroll was made but the first PL-SQL that I added remains visible and not the last. this is the class code. If any colleague can help me, I would appreciate it, thank you.

```
public class AutoScrollListView : ListView
    {
        private INotifyCollectionChanged _previousObservableCollection;

        public AutoScrollListView(ListViewCachingStrategy cachingStrategy)
            : base(cachingStrategy)
        {
        }

        public AutoScrollListView()
            : base()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);

            if (propertyName == nameof(ItemsSource))
            {
                if (_previousObservableCollection != null)
                {
                    _previousObservableCollection.CollectionChanged -= OnItemsSourceCollectionChanged;
                    _previousObservableCollection = null;
                }

                if (ItemsSource is INotifyCollectionChanged newObservableCollection)
                {
                    _previousObservableCollection = newObservableCollection;
                    newObservableCollection.CollectionChanged += OnItemsSourceCollectionChanged;
                }
            }
        }

        private void OnItemsSourceCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add || e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace)
            {
                foreach (var item in e.NewItems)
                {
                    // Scroll to the item that has just been added/updated to make it visible
                    ScrollTo(item, ScrollToPosition.End,true);
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) as an answer if it's helpful to others facing the same problem. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> Here, instead of scrolling to the last PL-SQL, it stays on the first, it shows me the animation that a scroll was made but the first PL-SQL that I added remains visible and not the last.

Because this:
[image]

> A linear search is done for the item, so if the same reference appears multiple times in the list, the first item will be scrolled to. This includes if grouping is enabled.

CollectionView can achieve your need:

AutoScrollCollectionView.cs

```cs
public class AutoScrollCollectionView : CollectionView
{
    private INotifyCollectionChanged _previousObservableCollection;

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged ([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        base.OnPropertyChanged (propertyName);

        if (propertyName == nameof (ItemsSource))
            {
                if (_previousObservableCollection != null)
                    {
                        _previousObservableCollection.CollectionChanged
                            -= OnItemsSourceCollectionChanged;
                        _previousObservableCollection = null;
                    }

                if (ItemsSource is INotifyCollectionChanged
                        newObservableCollection)
                    {
                        _previousObservableCollection = newObservableCollection;
                        newObservableCollection.CollectionChanged
                            += OnItemsSourceCollectionChanged;
                    }
            }
    }

    private void OnItemsSourceCollectionChanged (object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add || e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace)
            {
                ScrollTo (e.NewStartingIndex);
            }
    }
}
```

xaml:

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:control="clr-namespace:Forms1.CustomControls"
             x:Class="Forms1.Page1">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <control:AutoScrollCollectionView x:Name="collectionview">
                <control:AutoScrollCollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackLayout HeightRequest="100"
                                     Padding="70,30">
                            <Label Text="{Binding .}"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </control:AutoScrollCollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </control:AutoScrollCollectionView>
            
            <Button Text="click" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

xaml.cs:

```cs
public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
{
    ObservableCollection<string> myList;
    public Page1 ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        myList = new ObservableCollection<string> ();
        myList.Add ("C#");
        myList.Add ("Html");
        myList.Add ("T-SQL");
        myList.Add ("Python");
        myList.Add ("PL-SQL");

        collectionview.ItemsSource = myList;
        BindingContext = this;
    }

    private void Button_Clicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myList.Add ("PL-SQL");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks my friend with your answer I solved this problem, thanks again